# How to add multiple markers in google map in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to add multiple markers in my app. I have tried adding one marker using the following code:

```
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.List;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    LocationManager mLocationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        Location location = getLastKnownLocation();
        LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("You are here."));

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(userLocation));
    }

    private Location getLastKnownLocation() {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        List<String> providers = mLocationManager.getProviders(true);
        Location bestLocation = null;
        for (String provider : providers) {
            Location l = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            if (l == null) {
                continue;
            }
            if (bestLocation == null || l.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy()) {
                // Found best last known location: %s", l);
                bestLocation = l;
            }
        }
        return bestLocation;
    }
}
```

The following code works fine. Now, I want to add multiple markers. I tried adding these markers also in

```
     public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        Location location = getLastKnownLocation();
        LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("You are here."));
         mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(100,100)).title("You are here."));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(150,150)).title("You are here."));

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(userLocation));
    }
```

But it is not working fine. I am getting only one marker on the screen.

Comment: which code is not working?  describe your problem properly first

Comment: I am not getting multiple markers on screen.

Comment: I see just one marker?

Comment: You code looks OK. Have you searched the entire map?

Comment: @JiTHiN Have a look. I want to add more than one marker on the screen. But, I am getting only one marker on the screen.

Comment: what is `LatLng(100,100)` ? AFAIK its not a valid Latitude and Longitude

Comment: Yeah, thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinates you've given is wrong. The valid range of latitude in degrees is -90 and +90 for the southern and northern hemisphere respectively. Longitude is in the range -180 and +180 specifying the east-west position.

Comment: I need to revise geography concepts. :D